# Firebase in React - signInWithPopup() return a blank page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-oauth, firebase-authentication

i want try firebase for same project with google auth.

In my react project i have a button with this onPress function  =>

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

handleLogIn() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
      // ...
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // ...
    });
  }
```

But this return a blank page...any suggestion?

UPDATE: with signInWithRedirect() it works

Answer (score 1):

Blank page opens and closes if the user is already signed in and has provided the required permissions for the application. In that case, the app just returns the data.

Comment: yes, but the blank page remains open and not return the data.

Comment: Have you tried logging out the response data? What does it say?

Comment: Yes, it return `undefined`. See the video => https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7OLu7EN8ZW-RC1VM0QzbjU1RWc

Comment: Have you enabled this sign in method as in 'Before you begin' section: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin. If yes, please make sure to `console.log(error)`.

Comment: yes, of course. the console.log(error) in logout or login? In my logout function i have this => ```firebase.auth().signOut()
    .then((result) => console.log('result', result))
    .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));```

Comment: Log both result and error. Let me know what message do you get from the console.

Comment: The login functions open a blank page but return nothing. The logout functions return `result undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127554/discussion-between-deividas-karzinauskas-and-sarovin).

Answer (score 0):

```
handleLogIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
      // ...
    })enter code here
    .catch(function(error) {
      // ...
    });
  }
```

Comment: Would be much better if you accompanied your code with some explanation.

Comment: Please add some explanation to tour answer. Also, check this thread: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)